# Custom model method to get a relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to define a custom Model method in Laravel. I have a n:m relation between `Subscription` and `Notification` over `SubscriptionNotification`.

I already defined the default relations:

```
public function subscription_notifications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubscriptionNotification');
}

public function notifications() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notification', 'subscription_notifications');
}
```

Now I want to define a method, which returns a collection of notifications. I collect the IDs of the notifications I want in an array and write the following method:

```
public function notifications_due() {
    // Collect $notification_ids
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notification', 'subscription_notifications')->whereIn('notifications.id', $notification_ids)->get();
}
```

But when I want to use the mothod by `$subscription->notifications_due`, I get the following error:

```
[LogicException]
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

I'm new to Laravel (I come from Rails). I don't know if this is in Laravel even possible. Maybe someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `->get()` part in the method `notifications_due`. `get()` will return a Collection, but when calling the method as a property (or magic method), Laravel expects the method to return an instance of `Relation`. Laravel will then execute the query and transform it to a Collection automatically.

Also, you can use your already defined `notifications()` method:

```
public function notifications_due() {
    // Collect $notification_ids
    return $this->notifications()->whereIn('id', $notification_ids);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `get` call from your relationship method, for example:

```
public function notifications_due() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Notification',
        'subscription_notifications
    ')->whereIn('notifications.id', $notification_ids);
}
```

Use it just same:

```
// It'll return a collection
$dues = $subscription->notifications_due;
```

To get all the `id`s from the collection you may try this:

```
$ids = $dues->pluck('id');
```

Also, you may add more constraints if you want if you use it like:the

```
$dues = $subscription->notifications_due()->where('some', 'thing')->get();
```

Or paginate:

```
$dues = $subscription->notifications_due()->where('some', 'thing')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I can't accept both answers, but i upvoted yours.

Comment: Where can i put the relations for a a notification? Is there a Model class somewhere? I need to do many-to-many between notification and message for instance if multiple users are mentioned. :)